# Match the whole string that contains a known string

Tags: regex

I have a string like this `./this-needs-to-be-matched/knownstring/endofstring`.

I always know that the **endofstring** is 11 chars long

I have used this until I realized that the - sign will not be matched

```
\w+\/knownstring\/\w{11}
```

Now I don't really know how to match any char, including the minus sign.

The result should be: The result should be: `this-needs-to-be-matched/knownstring/endofstring`

I have also tried:

```
\.\/.*\/knownstring\/\w{11}
```

And different other variations so I'm stuck.

Comment: What language (javascript?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-` to the list of allowed chars:

```
^\.\/[\w-]+\/knownstring\/\w{11}$
```

or just "not a slash":

```
^\.\/[^\/]+\/knownstring\/\w{11}$
```

Comment: Interesting approach, didn;t knew you can add chars to the list of allowed chars and to be honest the 2nd approach it's still unclear. You matched anything that's between ./ and "not a slash"?

Comment: Just for the record I managed to come with a solution myself `[a-zA-Z0-9+-]+\/knownstring\/\w{11}`

Comment: `[^\/]` means "any character not a slash". The `^` *negates* the character class. btw, unless you're using javascript, ruby or some other language that uses the forward slash to delimit regexes, the forward slashes don't need escaping

Answer (score 0):

I think `\.\/.*\/knownstring\/\w{11}` should actually work, what exactly is wrong with this?

If `endofstring` needs to match exactly 11 characters and no more, you can add a word boundary symbol `\b`.

`\.\/.*\/knownstring\/\w{11}\b`

You can test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/LPpXoC/2).

Comment: because in both cases it does a greedy match and if I have another **./** somewhere in my string it will match all